# Mahout Precision Recall Movielens 10M

Tags: mahout

I'm new to Recommender Systems. I am trying to learn Mahout and so far I think that I have the grasp of it.

BUT, I encounter a rather peculiar problem when I try to calculate Precision & Recall with the example from the book Mahout in Action (Listing 2.4, page 21), for more convenience I copy paste the main body here:

```
RandomUtils.useTestSeed();
 DataModel model = new FileDataModel (new File("intro.csv"));
 RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator evaluator =
 new GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator ();
  RecommenderBuilder recommenderBuilder = new RecommenderBuilder() {
  @Override
   public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel model)
    throws TasteException {
    UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity (model);
    UserNeighborhood neighborhood =
     new NearestNUserNeighborhood (2, similarity, model);
      return
      new GenericUserBasedRecommender (model, neighborhood, similarity);
     }
   };
    IRStatistics stats = evaluator.evaluate(
    recommenderBuilder, null, model, null, 2,
    GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator.CHOOSE_THRESHOLD,
    1.0);
 System.out.println(stats.getPrecision());
 System.out.println(stats.getRecall());
```

When I try to execute the above using the small dataset found in the book, everything is as it should be. BUT, when I try to calculate Precision & Recall using Movielens 1M or 10M the results are horribly low... For example Precision and Recall @ 2 equals to:
P: 0.00573 and R: 0.005882

I am out of ideas, so if anyone has or had a similar problem I would be happy to hear that there is a solution...

Comment: hello, i am running the same evaluation on 1 m data set but it takes for ever to compute. can you remember how much time it takes on your data set

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Section 2.4.2 touches on the explanation: precision and recall tests are not so meaningful for recommenders since you don't actually know which items are "relevant" results. You can guess that the highly-rated items are relevant but you don't know whether unrated items are relevant or not. The test amounts to finding out how much the recommendations intersect the top-rated items, which is not quite what precision/recall needs to do.

So you get low scores. 10% is not bad, actually. Now, 0.5% is pretty poor, yes. It means this is not a good algorithm for this data set.

[Mean average precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Mean_average_precision), or [AUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_Under_the_Curve), would probably give you a little broader picture of the quality of the results, since they're looking at the behavior of a much larger range of results. These aren't implemented in Mahout (not in this part of the code anyway).

But they are in [Myrrix](http://myrrix.com/). I know that you will get 25+% precision/recall and 14+% mean average precision on the Grouplens 10M data set, since there's a [unit test for this](https://code.google.com/p/myrrix-recommender/source/browse/trunk/online/test/net/myrrix/online/eval/PrecisionRecallEvaluationTest.java). (I'm the author of this part of Mahout, and am commercializing it as Myrrix.) If you're looking for something that does a great job on this kind of data out of the box I think it will be worth your time to look at.

Comment: Thank you for the lighting-fast answer!!
I'll take into consideration of what you said and I will certainly take a closer look to Myrrix..

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem would be your neighborhood size. I remember seeing a article on neighborhood size that a size of 10 is few. Try with number above 10.

Comment: This should be a comment at best.